# How can I make a variable be the select Id in a getElement

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a variable be the select Id in a getElement? When I tried it, it returned null. My code is shown below:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p id = "test">hi</p>



  <script>
    var test = "test";
    document.getElementById(test).innerHTML = "complete";
  </script>

 </body
</html>
```

Comment: that's correct, it should work. btw your "body" closing tag is missing a `>`.

Comment: You may want to execute your Javascript only after the page has finished loading. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 2):

That code seems to work just fine (with the exception of the unclosed body tag), here is a runnable version of the code, fixed:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p id = "test">hi</p>



  <script>
    var test = "test";
    document.getElementById(test).innerHTML = "complete";
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Remember, the js code is going to happen almost immediately, so you won't be able to see the "hi" part. If you want it to change after like 1 second, use this:

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p id = "test">hi</p>



  <script>
    var test = "test";
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById(test).innerHTML = "complete";
    }, 1000);
  </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

All I changed in that, is put the `document.getElementById()` into a `setTimeout`

Hope this helped.